# How to format query results as CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, etl, data-manipulation

My goal: Automate the operation of executing a query and output the results into a csv.

I have been successful in obtaining the query results using Python (this is my first project ever in Python). I am trying to format these results as a csv but am completely lost. It's basically just creating 2 massive rows with all the data not parsed out. The .txt and .csv results are attached (I obtained these by simply calling the query and entering "file name > results.txt" or "file name > results.csv".

txt results: `{'data': {'get_result': {'job_id': None, 'result_id': '72a17fd2-e63c-4732-805a-ad6a7b980a99', '__typename': 'get_result_response'}}} {'data': {'query_results': [{'id': '72a17fd2-e63c-4732-805a-ad6a7b980a99', 'job_id': '05eb2527-2ca0-4dd1-b6da-96fb5aa2e67c', 'error': None, 'runtime': 157, 'generated_at': '2022-04-07T20:14:36.693419+00:00', 'columns': ['project_name', 'leaderboard_date', 'volume_30day', 'transactions_30day', 'floor_price', 'median_price', 'unique_holders', 'rank', 'custom_sort_order'], '__typename': 'query_results'}], 'get_result_by_result_id': [{'data': {'custom_sort_order': 'AA', 'floor_price': 0.375, 'leaderboard_date': '2022-04-07', 'median_price': 343.4, 'project_name': 'Terraforms by Mathcastles', 'rank': 1, 'transactions_30day': 2774, 'unique_holders': 2179, 'volume_30day': 744611.6252}, '__typename': 'get_result_template'}, {'data': {'custom_sort_order': 'AB', 'floor_price': 4.69471, 'leaderboard_date': '2022-04-07', 'median_price': 6.5, 'project_name': 'Meebits', 'rank': 2, 'transactions_30day': 4153, 'unique_holders': 6200, 'volume_30day': 163520.7377371168}, '__typename': 'get_result_template'},`  etc. (repeats for 100s of rows)..

Comment: Have you tried with `pandas`? In particular [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)? [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize#pandas.json_normalize) could also be of interest...

Comment: The CSV data format does not not support nested data-structures. Think of it as a simple 2D arrays or tables of data. I suggest you use some other format like JSON that does.

Comment: Please don't post links to off-site resources, especially those that other's can't access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `results` text string actually contains two dictionaries separated by a space character.
Here's a formatted version of what's in each of them:

```
dict1 = {'data': {'get_result': {'job_id': None,
                                 'result_id': '72a17fd2-e63c-4732-805a-ad6a7b980a99',
                                 '__typename': 'get_result_response'}}}

dict2 = {'data': {'query_results': [{'id': '72a17fd2-e63c-4732-805a-ad6a7b980a99',
                                     'job_id': '05eb2527-2ca0-4dd1-b6da-96fb5aa2e67c',
                                     'error': None,
                                     'runtime': 157,
                                     'generated_at': '2022-04-07T20:14:36.693419+00:00',
                                     'columns': ['project_name',
                                                 'leaderboard_date',
                                                 'volume_30day',
                                                 'transactions_30day',
                                                 'floor_price',
                                                 'median_price',
                                                 'unique_holders',
                                                 'rank',
                                                 'custom_sort_order'],
                                     '__typename': 'query_results'}],
                  'get_result_by_result_id': [{'data': {'custom_sort_order': 'AA',
                                                        'floor_price': 0.375,
                                                        'leaderboard_date': '2022-04-07',
                                                        'median_price': 343.4,
                                                        'project_name': 'Terraforms by Mathcastles',
                                                        'rank': 1,
                                                        'transactions_30day': 2774,
                                                        'unique_holders': 2179,
                                                        'volume_30day': 744611.6252},
                                               '__typename': 'get_result_template'},
                                              {'data': {'custom_sort_order': 'AB',
                                                        'floor_price': 4.69471,
                                                        'leaderboard_date': '2022-04-07',
                                                        'median_price': 6.5,
                                                        'project_name': 'Meebits',
                                                        'rank': 2,
                                                        'transactions_30day': 4153,
                                                        'unique_holders': 6200,
                                                        'volume_30day': 163520.7377371168},
                                               '__typename': 'get_result_template'},
                                             ]}}
```

(BTW I formatting them using the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#module-pprint) module. This is often a good first step when dealing with these kinds of problems — so you know what you're dealing with.)

Ignoring the first one completely and all but the repetitive data in the second — which is what I assume is all you really want — you could create a CSV file from the nested dictionary values in the `dict2['data']['get_result_by_result_id']` list. Here's how that could be done using the [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint  # If needed.


output_filepath = 'query_results.csv'

# Determine CSV fieldnames based on keys of first dictionary.
fieldnames = dict2['data']['get_result_by_result_id'][0]['data'].keys()

with open(output_filepath, 'w', newline='') as outp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # Optional.

    for result in dict2['data']['get_result_by_result_id']:
#        pprint(result['data'], sort_dicts=False)
        writer.writerow(result['data'])

print('fini')
```

Using the test data, here's the contents of the `'query_results.csv'` file it created:

```
custom_sort_order,floor_price,leaderboard_date,median_price,project_name,rank,transactions_30day,unique_holders,volume_30day
AA,0.375,2022-04-07,343.4,Terraforms by Mathcastles,1,2774,2179,744611.6252
AB,4.69471,2022-04-07,6.5,Meebits,2,4153,6200,163520.7377371168
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have the data in a python dictionary. The google sheet says access denied so I can't see the whole data.

But essentially you want to convert the dictionary data to a csv file.

At the bare bones you can use code like this to get where you need to. For your example you'll need to drill down to where the rows actually are.

```
import csv
new_path = open("mytest.csv", "w")
file_dictionary = {"oliva":199,"james":145,"potter":187}

z = csv.writer(new_path)
for new_k, new_v in file_dictionary.items():
    z.writerow([new_k, new_v])

new_path.close()
```

This guide should help you out.
https://pythonguides.com/python-dictionary-to-csv/

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question right, you should construct a dataframe format with your results and then save the dataframe in .csv format. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) library is usefull and easy to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).